# How can we set Company Administrator and password in tally xml?

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml

When i try to import data from java application to tally, I set company security as true in tally then it is required to check username and password also in XML ...but I didn't see any tags for setting username and password...Also if I logged in tally then it works fine,I can import data otherwise it shows error..I need to set username and password through xml ...